# Python: Creating an object with more than two optional arguments

Tags: python, object, initialization, arguments

```
class Disease:
  def __init__(self, category, name, nicknames, sx, *labs, **inheritance):
    self.category = category
    self.name = name
    self.nicknames = nicknames
    self.sx = sx
    self.labs = labs  #incl. vitals
    self.inheritance = inheritance
  def printLabs(self):
    for item in self.labs:
      print(item)
```

This works fine, but when I try to initialize a Disease with three optional values, or with the optional value in the middle (ie nicknames), it doesn't work.

Is there any way around these issues?

Comment: please give an example of what you mean. What doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a value *sometimes* optional, you either have to pull it from `*labs` or `**inheritance`, or provide a default value such as:

```py
class Disease:
  def __init__(self, category, name, nicknames=None, sx=None, *labs, **inheritance):
```

Now, if the user does not provide a value for nicknames, or sx, they remain as None.

*Note: Optional (default) arguments like this **must** be at the end of the function declaration - meaning you cannot do something like `def __init__(self, category, name=None, nicknames, sx, *labs, **inheritance)` because after `name`, all arguments must have default values or else you'll get a a `SyntaxError`.*

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To define a class with optional arguments , you should give initial value for those arguments , the initial value can be none or integer or String or whatever you want so that
if you want to initialize an instance from that class without giving values to those arguments it gets the value from the parent object
Make Sure to order arguments Positional Arguments come first